# JavaScript operator for "within x of"

Tags: javascript, html, operator-keyword, equality, inequalities

is there a JavaScript operator that will check proximity, kind of like a soft equals?  For example, instead of `if (a == b)` it would read `if (a is within 5 of b)`.  There is probably no such thing but it would be a big help if there was.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you can easily accomplish the same with this:

```
if ( Math.abs(a - b) <= 5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

nope, there's no such operator.

FYI, all operators can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Answer (score 0):

```
function isNearby(a, b, delta) {
   return Math.abs(a - b) <= delta;
}
```